# Creating a UIView subclass that can trigger segues

Tags: ios, segue, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

Instances of UIButton, UITableViewCell, etc can be used as segue sources in Interface Builder (i.e. you can ctrl-click those objects and link them to controllers in a storyboard).

Can we create a direct UIView subclass that allows the same functionality? If so, how?

**NOTE:** Here's another way to ask my question: how can I add items in the "Triggered Segues" section of my own classes? Here's what one can see for a UITableViewCell:

[image: Triggered Segue]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I liked to have the same functionality as Jean, I was puzzled. Disclaimer: I'm a total noob on iOS and Apple, so I assume it must be me and my lack of understanding why it's not working.

This 'answer' is more a theory, and maybe a very bad one. So please let me know if there' already a solution.

**Theory**

I do not think it is possible to extend/control the 'Triggered Segues' section via code alone. It seems like XCode knows based on the control chosen from the Object Library which Triggered Segues to display.

[image]

**Thoughts**

Having only a subclass of e.g. UIButton did not get me the Triggered Segues Section in the Connections Inspector. Setting the class in the Custom Class section does not help either.

[image]

Only when I use a Button from the Object Library, I get the Triggered Segues Section. E.g. if I subclass from UIButton, I should use a 'Button'.

[image]

I played around with the XML in my Main.storyboard - whenever I changed a `<subviews><button ...` to a `<subviews><view ...` the 'Triggered Segues' section is gone. Change it back and it appears. See below. I changed the element which contains the `customClass="IconButton"` attribute from button to view.

**Button: Having Triggered Segues**

```
<viewController title="..." id="Zzf-WE-vxI" customClass="MyCustomClass" ... >
    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Mfn-O2-CMJ">
        <!-- ... -->
        <subviews>
            <button customClass="IconButton" customModule="...">
                <!-- ... -->
            </button>
```

**View: No Triggered Segues**

```
<viewController title="..." id="Zzf-WE-vxI" customClass="MyCustomClass" ... >
    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Mfn-O2-CMJ">
        <!-- ... -->
        <subviews>
            <view customClass="IconButton" customModule="...">
                <!-- ... -->
            </view>
```

**Conclusion**

My conclusion is that XCode shows Triggered Segues section based on the element/control in a storyboard's XML - it is not dependent on the class I subclass from. So I doubt it's possible to control the contents of the Triggered Segues section by code.

Please let me know if I'm wrong. As said, I've got no real experience with the internals of XCode right now and I'm curious if my theory is just bla bla.

Comment: I never thought about comparing the XML under the hood! Very interesting, Seventy.

Comment: Looks like it's somehow hardwired, but as said, just a theory.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the control which fits better to your purpose.

Latter in Xcode you must place the name of the class in the right inspector and if it needs different options use key-propertyes.

The tab once you have selected the UIView is tooltiped as 'Show identity inspector'.

Then you can acces to the Custom Class area and you can select the class name.

A more sophisticated feature is using 'User Defined Runtime Attributes'

Comment: However, UITableViewCell is a subclass of UIView and still allows segues... How can I do it with my own UIView classes?

Comment: Just place the view in the location you like. Then in the 'Show identity inspector' Tab of the right menu you will be allowed to set the class name and properties (attributres) for your own project

Comment: @KikoAlbiolColomer BTW, "porpoise" is a male dolphin. And "to porpoise" means "moving like a dolphin" 

Comment: @JulianF.Weinert - simply click the button "Edit" to fix harmless typos.

Answer (score -1):

Yes from view controller to view controller create a segue in storyboard. YOU MUST give that segue an identifier. Then listen for touches began on that view and call [self performSegueWithIdentifier@"YOUR IDENTIFER"];

No you can not directly make a UIVIEW have an action. You can add a button
HERE ADD A BUTTON TO VIEW

```
UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];
[view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn addSubview:view];
[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(click)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

or add tap recognizer to view

```
//The setup code (in viewDidLoad in your view controller)
     UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = 
  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                      action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];

//The event handling method
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
  CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view superview]];

 //Do stuff here...
}
```

Comment: Good advice, but does not answer my question. Any idea how to allow a UIView subclass to become a segue source?

Comment: However, UITableViewCell is a subclass of UIView and still allows segues... How can I do it with my own UIView classes?

Comment: If you wanted to do it, why wouldnt you just use the UIVIEW method touches began? and say if view == myVIEW perform action? or add a touch recognizer to the view? Ill update further

Comment: It wouldn't allow me to use segues in a storyboard.

Comment: Why not? You had your view controller selected and control dragged to the next view controlleR?

Comment: You're right, I can connect segues between the 2 controllers... but I still wonder how UITableViewCell, UIButton, UITextField do to allow segues emanating directly from them.

Comment: They are extensions with that built in

Comment: if i solved your problem, accept my answer if you dont mind:)

Comment: Mike, please see the note I added to my question.

Comment: You wish to add that attribute to a UIVIEW?

Comment: To a UIView subclass.

Comment: No you cannot achieve this as of iOS9. The preferred way is to call your segueWithIdentifier method for view segues